# Importfeed not pulling in all results (googlesheets)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using =importfeed to pull in a Google Alert. It only gives me about 20 results, when I know there are more that are fed to me in my alert email (something like 50).

For example, I set an alert on Starbucks.  I went to the bottom of the email I received, and copied the address of the RSS feed, stuck that in cell A1, and appended ?output=atom.

This is the formula I have:
=importfeed(A1,"items title",true)

Here's what's in A1:
https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/10136724742523748721/15764223666146635885?output=atom

I've also added to the importfeed formula 10,20,100 after True for the desired query result.  10 gives me 10, 20 gives me 20, but 100 only gives me the 20, and no specification gives me 20.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I counted 20 titles only

Comment: But there is definitely more than 20 results.  The email that I got originally (that I pulled the RSS Feed link from), gave me 69 results.

Comment: Also, it did seem to update overnight with additional news items, but again, it was only 20 items (and the associated email I got was definitely more than 20).